# Sorting my ArrayAdapter doesn't change my data source

Tags: java, android, sorting, android-arrayadapter

I am having a weird issue. I have an ArrayAdapter which I am sorting. This displays properly on my screen, however when I check the actual data source, the contents have not been sorted. How can I ensure that sorting my ListAdapter will also sort my data source?

```
Collections.sort(quotes, new PercentChangeComparator()); //sort my data source (this isn't necessary)
quotesAdapter.sort(new PercentChangeComparator()); //sort my ListAdapter
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),quotes.get(0).getSymbol(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show(); //this shows that my data source hasn't been updated, even though my ListAdapter presents my ListView in the correctly sorted order.
```

For example:
If my data source is `[10,9,1,20]`

after sorting my ListView will show `[1,9,10,20]`

but the data source will still be `[10,9,1,20]`

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the other way round: sorting your data source will order the ArrayAdapter.

I assume you've done something like this before.

```
ArrayList<PercentChangeComparator> quotes = getQuotesFromSomewhere();
QuotesAdapter quotesAdapter = new QuotesAdapter(this, R.layout.xxx, quotes);
```

Then, if you sorted quotes, notifying the adapter that the dataSet has changed should sort the list

```
Collections.sort(quotes, new PercentChangeComparator());
quotesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This is working for me, I hope it helps.

One important thing: if you recreate the source array (*quotes* in this specific example), the Adapter won't read further changes. Thus, if you need to modify the content of your ListView, do:

```
quotes.clear();
quotes.add(...);
quotes.add(...);
```

Also, make sure you implemented correctly the Comparator. If you execute this

```
Collections.sort(quotes, new PercentChangeComparator());
```

and *quotes* isn't sorted, then the problem isn't related to the Adapter but to the comparation.